# First-order non-linear differential equation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I have this equation:

$$x(dx-dy) + y(dx+dy) = 0  $$
I tried to solve it by turning it to fraction-type:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$$
However, I realized that it's not homogeneous, and now I am stuck. 
Please help!

Comment: Hint: right hand side: $\frac{1+y/x}{1-y/x}$. Let $u=y/x, \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}x+u$.

Comment: @KittyL thanks! it can then be reduced to separable variables,is there any other standard method for solving this particular type?

Comment: I didn't see any other way to solve the original equation. This substitution rule is typical. It can be used when the right hand side of $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ can be written as a function of $y/x$.

Comment: @KittyL got you!

Comment: if you know a little bit of linear algebra, you will find the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}$ to be $1\pm i$ and $e^{At} = e^t\pmatrix{\cos t & -\sin t\\\sin t & \cos t}$ for the $\frac{d}{dt} (x,y)^T = A(x,y)^T.$

Answer (score 0):

It is also of interest to solve it in polar coordinates :

[image]